# Running a Julia file in a Python Script

Tags: python, julia

I want to run a Julia file inside a Python Script. The Julia file is

func1.jl

```
using LowRankApprox

using LinearAlgebra

function f(A)

    F = pqrfact(A)

    M = A * F[:P]

    return M

end

function k(A)

    F = pqrfact(A)

    k = F[:k]

    return k

end
```

This code is working perfectly in Atom. But I need it to work inside a Python Script.
My Python Script is:

```py
import numpy as np

import julia

j = julia.Julia()

j.include("func1.jl")

A = np.array([[1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1]])

print(j.k(A))
```

Gives the following error:

`FileNotFoundError`

I've tried to put the Julia file in several folders but it always gives the same message.
If anyone can help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Your python interpreter is probably not looking for files in the place you expect. Try running the following in python.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This will tell you where python starts looking for files. If you put your julia file there, your code should work. You can also run `os.chdir(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'directory', 'containing', 'julia', 'file'))`, or `j.include(os.path.join('absolute', 'path', 'to', 'func1.jl'))`.

If you're using Hydrogen to run Python code in Atom, you might want to check out [how to change where the Python interpreter starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938106/using-atom-with-hydrogen-the-working-directory-for-atom-is-one-folder-up-from-t).

Comment: @emersonDid not work. It keeps giving the same error message.

Comment: @RitadeCassiaSouzaPaz I can only suggest that you check the output of `os.getcwd()` very carefully and make sure that everything is spelled correctly. If you think you know the path to the directory containing `func1.jl`, you can use `os.listdir('path/to/dir')` to make sure the file is really there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by placing the path in the system variable and with the following code in Python:

import julia
from julia.api import Julia

julia.install()

jl = Julia(compiled_modules=False)

j = julia.Julia()
j.include('func1.jl')